# multiple post requests within an observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs, nest

I need to make multiple post requests until a certain condition is met, since the response has a property to make another request ( example "is more").

I don't know which rxjs operator I can use to make multiple requests, concatenate them all and close the observable when the "isMore" returns a false.

I am using httpService from nest.js with axios.

if you can help me thank you very much

multiple responses to a post request until a condition is met

Comment: it seems `expand` operator is exactly the one you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you will be calling the same single endpoint, you can use `takeWhile` operation. The idea is like below:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const fetchDataUntilNoMore = (baseUrl, endpoint) => {
  return from(axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${endpoint}`)).pipe(
    takeWhile((response) => response.data.isMore),
    catchError((error) => {
      // Handle any errors here
      return of(error);
    })
  );
};
```

Then, you can subscribe to this function in your Next.js component.